# What are the hollow arrows in my .xcdatamodel?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I was looking through my .xcdatamodel and I noticed that there was an arrow that doesn't seem to represent anything(I can't post images so here's an example behind a link): 
http://s1.postimage.org/2ufcjo0jo/Screen_shot_2011_05_01_at_8_16_14_PM.png
What does this represent? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Heh, that confused me the first time I saw it as well. It seems backwards to the way that inheritance is normally displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those arrows mean that one entity is a child of another. It goes from the child entity to the parent entity.